# How to Set ion-fab-buttons order in ion-fab-list constantly

Tags: ionic3, floating-action-button

I have this ion-fab-list

```
<ion-fab-list side="top">
      <button *ngIf="!loggedIn" [navPush]="Signup" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="md-clipboard" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>register</ion-label>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="!loggedIn" [navPush]="Login" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="log-in" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Login</ion-label>
      </button>

      <button [navPush]="cartPage" (click)="fab.close()" *ngIf="loggedIn" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="cart" color="danger"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>cart</ion-label>
      </button>
      <button [navPush]="MyordersPage" *ngIf="loggedIn" [navParams]="{'userId': user.id}" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="logo-buffer" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>My orders</ion-label>
      </button>

      <button (click)="platform.exitApp();" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="log-out" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Exit</ion-label>
      </button>

    </ion-fab-list>

  </ion-fab>
```

I want to show "Exit" button in ion-fab-list at the end of list, but it appears at the top!

[image]

Is there any way to fix the position of buttons in ion-fab-list?

Answer (score 1):

Fab buttons should be reverse ordered because they work as a stack. Put exit button at the top.

```
<ion-fab-list side="top">
      <button (click)="platform.exitApp();" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="log-out" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Exit</ion-label>
      </button>

      <button *ngIf="!loggedIn" [navPush]="Signup" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="md-clipboard" color="primary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>register</ion-label>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="!loggedIn" [navPush]="Login" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="log-in" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Login</ion-label>
      </button>

      <button [navPush]="cartPage" (click)="fab.close()" *ngIf="loggedIn" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="cart" color="danger"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>cart</ion-label>
      </button>
      <button [navPush]="MyordersPage" *ngIf="loggedIn" [navParams]="{'userId': user.id}" (click)="fab.close()" ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="logo-buffer" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>My orders</ion-label>
      </button>

    </ion-fab-list>

  </ion-fab>
```